# Summing together 2 or more VLOOKUPs in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have a cell which needs to sum together 3 different values, but I don't want to use relative/absolute cell references because the source data changes every year so the cell references would need re-pointing every year.

I've used VLOOKUPs for cells which only need to show 1 value and that's all fine, but I cannot find a way to add together the outcomes of 2 or more VLOOKUPs.  Also, each of the 3 values have different criteria, and I think I therefore need 3 separate VLOOKUP functions.

Is there a way of doing this?

This is the formula I've used, which returns a '**#N/A**' error:

**=vlookup("10000",datatable,3,false)+vlookup("10001",datatable,3,false)+vlookup("10002"),datatable,3,false)+...etc etc etc.**

Many thanks in advance
Rob

Comment: You are getting a #N/A because one or more of the looked up value is not present in the looked up array. Use IFERROR or IFNA functions to handle the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple example of summing 3 VLOOKUPs:

```
=SUM(VLOOKUP("A",A1:B3,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP("E",A5:B7,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP("I",A9:B11,2,FALSE))
```

I put 3 simple tables, each 3 rows and 2 columns, and added the lookup values together. So I look up `A` and return `1`, `E` and return `5`, `I` and return `9`. Then I sum them and return `15`. :-)

Comment: Hi Brian, so I found a very similar solution:                                                                                                =SUM(IFERROR(VLOOKUP("STAFFCST",DATATABLE,3,FALSE),0)+SUM(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(17080,DATATABLE,3,FALSE),0)+SUM(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(17073,DATATABLE,3,FALSE),0))))                                                                               Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Providing the only part to vary is the *lookup_value* (as appears to be so in your case) then, instead of writing multiple distinct `VLOOKUP` clauses followed by summing them (which could result in an extremely long construction indeed), you can use a single, equivalent `VLOOKUP` set-up.

So instead of, for example:

`=VLOOKUP("X",DataTable,3,FALSE)+VLOOKUP("Y",DataTable,3,FALSE)+VLOOKUP("Z",DataTable,3,FALSE)`

we can use the shorter:

`=SUM(VLOOKUP(T(IF(1,{"X","Y","Z"})),DataTable,3,FALSE))`

or, for more flexibility, if we have "X", "Y" and "Z" within a contiguous range somewhere within the worksheet, e.g. `H1:H3`, then:

`=SUM(VLOOKUP(T(IF({1},H1:H3)),DataTable,3,FALSE))`

If the criteria are not text strings, but numerics, then we can use `N` instead of `T`: for example, if we were looking for, not "X", "Y" and "Z", but 1, 2 and 3, then we would use:

`=SUM(VLOOKUP(N(IF(1,{1,2,3})),DataTable,3,FALSE))`

or:

`=SUM(VLOOKUP(N(IF({1},H1:H3)),DataTable,3,FALSE))`

If our criteria comprise a mixture of text and numerics, e.g. "X", 2 and "Z", then we need a slightly different approach, though I will leave that to another post!

References:

https://excelxor.com/2014/09/05/index-returning-an-array-of-values/

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Good heavens. Stop using `VLOOKUP`, everyone. `INDEX`together with `MATCH` is cleaner, neater and less prone to errors.

Now, for what you are doing, you don't need either. Why not check out `SUMIFS`

In your case it would look something like this

```
=SUMIFS(Sumcolumn;Criteriacolumn;10000;Criteriacolumn2;10001,...)
```

And, even if your sumcolumns are different from each other - it is still easier to sum several sumifs than it is to sum several vlookups, since vlookup will throw a `#N/A` if empty reference, whereas sumifs will return `0`. If you have a desire to be extra efficient with just one formula, use `SUMPRODUCT` - however that is a formula that needs some practice to write.